# In verilog is legal to implement a reset using assign?

Tags: fpga, verilog

I am trying to add a reset to a counter and I have this code, that syntethize perfectly:

```
module syncRX(clk, signal, detect);
    input clk, signal;
    output [7:0] detect;
    
    reg [7:0] detect_aux = 8'b0;
    reg rst;
    assign detect = detect_aux & ~rst;
    
    freq_div div(.clk(clk), .clk_1khz(clk_1khz));
    
    always @(posedge signal)
        rst <= 1;
        
    always @(posedge clk_1khz)
        detect_aux <= detect_aux + 1;
     
endmodule // top

module freq_div(input clk, output reg clk_1khz);
    reg [12:0] count = 0;
    always @(posedge clk)
     begin
        if(count == 6000)
            begin
                clk_1khz <= ~clk_1khz;
                count <= 0;
            end
        else
            count <= count + 1;
     end
endmodule
```

The problem is that

```
    reg rst;
    assign detect = detect_aux & ~rst;
```

Seams do nothingh. Is legal that I am trying?
Thanks

Comment: It does nothing because `rst` is always 0.

Comment: Also, given the way you're driving it, `rst` should be a `reg`, not a `wire`.

Comment: Ups! Thanks Dave, you are right, I just fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as already stated, you never change the value from rst to '1'

next, your rst is no reset in terms of chipdesign, but a clear signal, so rename it to clr.

"all" about real resets for modules:
http://www.asic-world.com/tidbits/all_reset.html

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in comments, in your code `rst` is always 0, therefore it will never affect the value of `detect`. If you want the reset to happen, you should make `rst` an input to your module, and then set it high at some point in your test bench.

But you should also notice that this isn't really a reset behavior. Setting `rst` high will force the `detect` output of the module to go to zero, but as soon as `rst` goes low again `detect` will return to its previous value as stored in `detect_aux`. If this were a proper reset, we'd expect the counting to start anew from 0 after `rst` is released.